# Duvida sobre React-Router

Tags: react, react-router, react-navigation

Meu App.jsx possui um BrowserRouter com Nav, Footer e entre eles as routes, porém quero um /admin que não renderize o Nav e Footer. Porém necessariamente quando adiciono /admin no routes ele puxa Nav e Footer. Alguém pode me ajudar

App.jsx:

```
export default props =>
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="app">
        <Nav />
        <Routes />
        <Footer />
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Router.js

```
export default props =>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/noticias/' component={Noticias} />
    <Route path='/produtos/' component={Produtos} />
    <Route path='/academicos/' component={Academicos} />
    <Route path='/login/professores/' component={LoginProfessores} />
    <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
</Switch>
```

Comment: vc utiliza state no App.jsx? (eu consegui uma forma usando state e context)

Comment: só que a forma que eu consegui, não renderiza nav e footer quando sair de /admin

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa separar as rotas comuns das rotas de admin.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
// OtherRoutes.jsx
export function OtherRoutes(props){
    return (
        <div>
            <nav/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={`/`} component={Home} />
                <Route path={`/noticias`} component={Noticias} />
                <Route path={`/produtos`} component={Produtos} />
                <Route path={`/academicos`} component={Academicos} />
                <Route path={`/login/professores`} component={LoginProfessores} />       
            </Switch>
            <footer/>
        </div>
    )
}

//Routes.jsx
export function Routes () {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/admin' component={AdminComponent} />
                <Route path='/' component={OtherRoutes}>
                <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```